# Unreal Engine 5 fails to start on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: segmentation-fault, libc, ubuntu-22.04, unreal-engine5, unreal

On Ubuntu 22.04 freshly installed from Server ISO (`Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS x86_64 5.15.0-91-generic`) UE5 fails to start with SIGSEGV in libc.6.so. Engine does not tell any details about function which caused crash. It happens just after showing the loading screen on 0%. Log details:

```
[2024.01.06-16.50.17:131][  0]LogInit: Using SDL_WINDOW_VULKAN
[2024.01.06-16.50.17:131][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: Built with Vulkan header version 1.3.239
[2024.01.06-16.50.17:132][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Starting Vulkan Profile check for VP_UE_Vulkan_SM5_RT:
MESA-INTEL: warning: Haswell Vulkan support is incomplete
Signal 11 caught.
Malloc Size=262146 LargeMemoryPoolOffset=262162 
CommonUnixCrashHandler: Signal=11
[2024.01.06-16.50.17:463][  0]LogCore: === Critical error: ===
Unhandled Exception: SIGSEGV: invalid attempt to read memory at address 0x0000000000000000

[2024.01.06-16.50.17:463][  0]LogCore: Fatal error!

0x00007fd6dca12520 libc.so.6!UnknownFunction(0x4251f)

[2024.01.06-16.50.17:504][  0]LogExit: Executing StaticShutdownAfterError
```

Engine version is 5.3.2 built from source. Crash persists on 5.3.1 and binary 5.3.2.
Output of nvidia-smi:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 390.157                Driver Version: 390.157                   |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Quadro K1100M       Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   46C    P0    N/A /  N/A |    143MiB /  1999MiB |      3%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

Output of Unreal.log:

```
[2024.01.06-16.50.17:131][  0]LogInit: Using SDL_WINDOW_VULKAN
[2024.01.06-16.50.17:131][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: Built with Vulkan header version 1.3.239
[2024.01.06-16.50.17:132][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Starting Vulkan Profile check for VP_UE_Vulkan_SM5_RT:
[2024.01.06-16.50.17:463][  0]LogCore: === Critical error: ===
Unhandled Exception: SIGSEGV: invalid attempt to read memory at address 0x0000000000000000

[2024.01.06-16.50.17:463][  0]LogCore: Fatal error!

0x00007fd6dca12520 libc.so.6!UnknownFunction(0x4251f)

[2024.01.06-16.50.17:504][  0]LogExit: Executing StaticShutdownAfterError
```

Diagnostics:

```
Generating report for minidump

Application version 5.3.2.0
 ... built from changelist 0

OS version Linux 5.15.0-91-generic (network name: thicc-pad)
Running 2 x86_64 processors (4 logical cores)
Exception was "SIGSEGV: invalid attempt to read memory at address 0x0000000000000000"

<SOURCE START>
<SOURCE END>

<CALLSTACK START>
libc.so.6!UnknownFunction(0x4251f)

<CALLSTACK END>

0 loaded modules

Report end!
```

It was working flawlessly on Ubuntu 20.04, however few days ago I have installed fresh Ubuntu 22.04. Epic claims that it even is recommended system for Linux Unreal development.

What I tried:

- built UE5 from source and started it
  What I expected:
- UE5 starting normally
  What happened:
- UE5 crashes immediately on startup with libc.so.6 segmentation fault

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: With the haswell message, it seems it's trying to use your cpu's integrated graphics instead of your dedicated GPU(assuming you have one).

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am running into the same problem